# SonataUserBundle requirements problems with Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, sonata-user-bundle

I'am trying to require "sonata-project/user-bundle" with composer, but get following error:

```
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.4 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.3 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.2 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.1 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.0 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.2 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4].
```

My composer.json require section:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "pixassociates/sortable-behavior-bundle": "^1.3",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.23",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.2",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.2",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
```

Actually i don't understand, why "sonata-project/user-bundle" requires "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3" if Symfony 2.8+ supported only by "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~2.0" .

So can I use Symfony 3.3 with "sonata-project/user-bundle" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you have to use the 4.x branch of SonataUserBundle which is still in developpement (already pretty stable however) :

> "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",

More information on dependencies on packagist : https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle

Answer (score 0):

yes you should you use

```
  "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
```

and you also have to change

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
```

in composer.json file this will sure work